# Open Flex Datefield Calendar to Beginning of the SelectabeRange Instead of the End of it

Tags: apache-flex, datefield

I've got a Flex 3 datefield like this:

```
<mx:DateField id="myDateSelector"    
        selectableRange="{{ rangeStart : new Date(2011,0,1), rangeEnd: new Date(2011,3,30) }}" 
         />
```

It works fine. Jan 1, 2011 through April 30, 2011 are selectable. The only problem is that when you click on the calendar icon, it opens to April, the last month that is selectable. Is it possible to have it open to the beginning of the selectable range, Jan.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, you sure like asking the same question in different context.  Also, do some research before posting anything, this is getting ridiculous.

```
<mx:DateField selectedDate="{new Date(2011,0,1)}" selectableRange="{{ rangeStart : new Date(2011,0,1), rangeEnd: new Date(2011,3,30) }}" />
```

Next question, I'm flagging you for not even trying.

Comment: Hi J_A_X, Thank you foe the help. I was struggling with this problem for a week. I don't think that I asked the same question. In any event, thanks.